# powershell azure find autoscale settings for classic vm

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-vm-role

I have a lot of classic Azure services with classic VMs some have auto scale setting and some don't. Is there a way through powershell I can find out if a classic Azure services has AutoScale set or not. looking at Get-AzureService and Get-AzureVM does not seem to have this information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, classic service display in ARM resource group, so we can use this command `Get-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting` to list autoscale enable or no on-configure.

```
Get-AzureRmAutoscaleSetting -ResourceGroup jasonnew
```

[image]

If the cloud service autoscale is enable, we will get the result, if not, nothing will output.

Also, we can use Azure portal to get the information:
[image]